# Creating multiple Excel rows from XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

tree=et.parse('test.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

Title= []
Date= []

for title in root.iter('title'):
    Title.append(title.text)

for date in root.iter('date'):
    Date.append(date.text)

print(Title)
print(Date)

Jobs_df = pd.DataFrame(
                       list(zip(Title,Date)), 
                       columns=['Title', 'Date'])
                       
                                       
Jobs_df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Ver>55</Ver>
    <data>
        <title>abcd'</title>
        <date>2011-11-12</date>
        <ID>Asdf123</ID>
    </data>
    <data>
        <title>efgg'</title>
        <ID>Asdf123</ID>
    </data>

</Report>
```

So I already managed to parse the date and title, although the 'title' appears twice. When I print the Title array it prints me two values "abcd" and "efgg". But when I convert it to the csv file, it only shows one row with the first value "abcd" and the "efgg" is skipped. How do I create a second row with exact the same information, but with different Titles?

What I got now:

```
Title  Date
abcd   2011-11-12
```

What I want:

```
Title  Date
abcd   2011-11-12
efgg   2011-11-12
```

How do I achieve that? Whats worth mentioning is, the second value efgg has to reuse the already existing information (date), I need all the previous information in new row, but with only the Title value changed

Comment: zip() iterates over the shortest list given, that's why you don't get the extra row.   Does your XML contain only one date tag at the beginning or are there multiple present, but with gaps in between? In the latter case should data points with missing dates infer value always from previous ones with known date?

Comment: @JacekJaskólski the Title [] array contains 2 or more values at the end, others remain with 1 value. I want a row to be created, if 2 or more values are in the "title" array, the other columns should copy the values from the single input arrays (date, ID and other...). Shouldnt zip() give me two values in one row, separated by comma? How else can I duplicate the rows with only title adjusted?

Comment: it would be helpful if you included a bigger sample of your xml file.

Comment: Try this: `Date += [Date[-1]] * (len(Title)-len(Date))` before creating the DataFrame

Comment: This will extend the `Date` list to match the length of `Title` by duplicating the last value of `Date` the appropriate number of times.

Comment: A robust solution would be to iterate over <data> and appending Title and Date at the same time, with a default for Date if empty.

Comment: @JacekJaskólski maybe an easier solution would be to just print the two titles in one row, in the same cell? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over <title> and <date> tags separately will generate a mess. Instead, iterate over <data> and use tha last recorded value of <date> if it's not present in the current <data> tag.

This should do the trick:

```py
Title = []
Date = []
last_date = None

for data in root.iter('data'):
  Title.append(data.find('title').text)
  date_el = data.find('date')
  if date_el != None:
    Date.append(date_el.text)
    last_date = date_el.text
  else:
    Date.append(last_date)
   
print(Title)
print(Date)
```

Comment: what does it do differently?

Comment: As stated in the answer: this code iterates over the Data tag, not Title and Date.
this way, you're able to control at which indices of the list there are missing dates and fill the values. Did you try running the code? If it doesn't produce the result you're after then I might've misunderstood your question. In any case  a bigger sample of the xml along with the desired result would be helpful to fully understand it.